# Can I farm underground in Minicraft?

Tags: minicraft

I'm not sure if it cares that there's no sunlight or not; I haven't actually tried yet though because I never seem to have any seeds to spare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [reddit post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbAAe.jpg), it is possible.

This is the image that was posted as proof. [image]

Comment: I can confirm that, but I think lanterns are necessary